# How to debug Project files which have different languages using NetBeans? 

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I need to debug a few files in the same project (using NetBeans) which have different languages (python and javascript). I found out how to set up debugger for current project but there is only one option available for debugger.

How to enable "multiple" debuggers?